# Log the why of the activity is resumed

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Is there a way to know if a activity's onresume is called because "back button" or if is called because the intire application Was in background ? 
I have to log this different actions :/
This is the scenario : 
I have 4 activity A-B-C-D ;  i need to log the navigation between activity and i don't want to log the onresume caused by Application wake from background:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Activity A, when you will start the Activity B/C/D, use and identifier and start the activity for result.

For example:

```
int ActivityBID = 1;
Intent i = new Intent(this,  ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ActivityBID );
```

In your Activity B you override the `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("activity","B")
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
   finish();
}
```

And backing to Activity A:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == ActivityBID ) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
             String stredittext=data.getStringExtra("activity");
         }     
    }
}
```

Note: The inner if and the variable is not necessary, because you already know what activity you result are from, but, i think you may want to pass some data in this return, so i leave then.

**Edit** Image exemplify the `ActivityForResult`

[image: Imagem]

Comment: In this way i only write the log if on back pressed event occurs ? For instance : A-B-C-B with this method I will write only B if the user close the app without return to the A ?

Comment: This way, you can log inside the `onActivityResult`, so the code will only be dispatched if the intent has an ActivityResult, when you close the APP, this don't occurs. You can create other variables like ActivityBID, to identify witch Activity the results are from.

Comment: But in your code is the setresult called only if the user press the back button ?

Comment: The only part who set the result is in the back, so yes. If you wanna, you can pass some identifier inside the set result and debug another situations

Comment: Then with this method I will not print anything  in the following navigation : A-B-C ?

Comment: If you start the Activity C using `startActivityforResult` from Activity B, the Activity B will have the result. I will post an Image with some explanation

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiroi have to try this method. But maybe the only problem is the first activity opened . I have to test !

Comment: You APP  start in several Activity's ? You can log the onCreate method to see which is started first. Or maybe you can always init on on activity and start all the other using start for result

Answer (score 1):

When an `Activity` is paused, `onPause()` is called. In `onPause()` write the name of the `Activity` that is being paused into a global `static` variable.

When an `Activity` is resumed, `onResume()` is called. In `onResume` check if the global `static` variable contains the name of this `Activity`. If it does, you can omit the logs because this `Activity` was just paused/resumed.

Comment: This way have a little problem. If the navigation is A-B-A-C , you will write only A-B-C .

Comment: No. When returning to A from B, `B.onPause()` is called (will write "B" to the global), then `A.onResume()` is called (will see that the global is not "A", so it will log "A"). Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance override the `onBackPressed()` callback

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    /* add your log here */
}
```

Collecting the log from `onResume()` plus the one (if any) coming from `onBackPressed()` then you can detect the various scenarios.

Comment: I have 4 activity A-B-C-D ;  i need to log the navigation between activity and i don't want to log the onresume caused by Application wake from background:)